# Vercel cannot find ./context/UserContext in './src'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

**This is the log:**

```
11:12:46.468    [4/4] Building fresh packages...
11:12:47.213    Done in 52.44s.
11:12:47.425    Running "yarn run build"
11:12:47.598    yarn run v1.22.10
11:12:47.624    $ react-scripts build
11:12:48.895    Creating an optimized production build...
11:12:50.134    Failed to compile.
11:12:50.134    ./src/App.js
11:12:50.135    Cannot find file './context/UserContext' in './src'.
11:12:50.176    error Command failed with exit code 1.
11:12:50.177    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
11:12:50.192    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

> I tried to build it local and it works fine, but when i deploy it that
> happend.